# div element visibility in outlook mails

Tags: outlook, html-email

I'm trying to send an html email through vb code . For this i've a template and the body is replaced using code. In the content of the email there are 3 images but one particular image is not to be displayed in one of the emails. So the image is put in the `div` tag and using style as `<div name="divA" style="display: none;">` display is switched off. Code runs and mails is sent successfully. When a mail having this line of code in body is seen in outlook the image is as expected **invisible**. 
 Problem arises when I forward this mail (using forward feature of outlook) to my friend the invisible image shows  up out of nowhere ! 
**Question**: How to make the image invisible so that it stays invisible upon forwarding as well ?

Answer (score 2):

Try this code, it's a little more bulletproof in addressing various things that email clients do / don't support:

```
<div style="display:none;font-size:1px;line-height:1px;max-height:0px;max-width:0px;opacity:0;overflow:hidden;mso-hide:all;">
    Your <img> tag
</div>
```

---

This is the code I've been using to hide [preview text](https://litmus.com/blog/the-ultimate-guide-to-preview-text-support) for the last few years, which I haven't seen appear when emails are forwarded. Never tried it with an image.

Comment: Ted, you beat me to it. I have tried it with image. The problem is the image has to have a width and height or 1px or 0px. You can control the width and height in media query afterwards.

Comment: @Ted Goas seems not helping me! I tried with 1px or 0px but when the mail is forwarded using outlook forward feature the image shows up :( !

Comment: Please let me know if you need more info on this. suggested solution is not helping me.

Comment: @EetSandhu I'm afraid I don't have much more to add. Forwarding from Outlook is a nasty case. Have you tried using a class to hide the image? [Outlook actually _does_ support the `<style>` tag](https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/).